# What does RESERVERD0 in Registers like USART1 in stm32f103 mean in stm32f10x.h header file? And how do I define a custom struct for the same?

Tags: c, struct, stm32

So recently I started bare-metal programming an stm32f103 device, and I was referring a builtin file "stm32f10x.h" in Keil uVision5, and I came across the **TypeDef** of USART struct it was like,

```
      typedef struct
      {
      __IO uint16_t SR;
      uint16_t  RESERVED0;
      __IO uint16_t DR;
      uint16_t  RESERVED1;
      __IO uint16_t BRR;
      uint16_t  RESERVED2;
      __IO uint16_t CR1;
      uint16_t  RESERVED3;
      __IO uint16_t CR2;
      uint16_t  RESERVED4;
      __IO uint16_t CR3;
      uint16_t  RESERVED5;
      __IO uint16_t GTPR;
      uint16_t  RESERVED6;
      } USART_TypeDef;
```

And I could not able to find any declaration or reference for these **RESERVEDx** registers. And if I want to define one custom struct for this register how do I do it? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you browse `stm32f103` datasheet and see how bits are allocated for usart register? Which bits are unused in the SR register for uart0?

Comment: @KamilCuk I generally agree, however for STM32 it's actually "reference manual" that I would recommend to peek into for such information. Just to make OP's googling easier ;)

Comment: It's just holes in the memory map that shouldn't be accessed, nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

They are not `RESERVEDx` registers only higher word of the 32 bit register which should not be touched. Simply ignore them, do not touch them, do not think about them.

Comment: Yes, I know, but how do I define my own struct in which even RESERVEDx are defined as of course reserved?

Comment: same as above. I do not understand your problem